# How to fix ".webp" being auto-added to the end of image urls

Tags: images, html

Idk what's causing this. Only thing I can think of is I migrated briefly to Cloudflare and came back. It's adding extra code to the end of the image url and breaks the path. Anyone seen this?

```
https://wp-content/uploads/2021/03/image1234-534x462.jpg.pagespeed.ic.GLD2ZB_jm4.webp
```

Comment: I'd search all of the code in your site (plugins and themes) for webp. I didn't know Cloudflare did that, but yes it looks like a CDN has converted all of your images to webp format at their end. You should also try and work out if the post content in the database has been changed with the .webp file extensions or if it's being done dynamically by a (now misinformed) plugin. I'd start by looking at any plugins you have called 'pagespeed'.

Comment: A google pagespeed Apache module setting was the culprit. Had my host disable it. Others have had the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079350/how-to-disable-webp-optimization-only